# Updating a .jar file that is in use

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have a C# program that updates and then launches a Java application.  Before actually launching Java, it checks for updates to the .jar files that program uses.  It's possible that multiple people are running the application on a given machine at one time (it could be a terminal server) or that the same user is running multiple instances of the program.  If other people are running the application, the .jar file will be in use and can't be updated.  I'm trying to work around this.

My preference would be to rename the .jar file and update it.  All the people currently running the application can still use the renamed jar file.  Windows won't let you rename a file that's in use, either (though I think Unix systems will).

I noticed that with Windows Explorer, though, you can copy/paste a jar file and overwrite a .jar file that's in use.  How does that work, and can I somehow do something similar in my  updater/launcher program?

Are there any other approaches I might use?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that there is no (easy) way to achieve this.  The few ideas I can think of might be to;

- Download the updates into a separate download location.  Each time the application is launched, try and install the updates, if any fail, rollback and try again later.
- Use some kind of lock file to indicate the either the program is running or an update is in progress and take action accordingly.  For example.  If you have updates and the "running" and "update" lock file do not exist, create an "update" lock file and install the updates, deleting the "update" lock when your done.  If you do way updates and the "update" lock file exists, wait until the "update" lock file is removed, you may want to check the updates again before installing them.  If you have updates and the "running" lock exists, you will have to skip the update process...
- Tell all connected users that they will be forcefully disconnected and the server restarted after some time period.  When the time period is up, kill the running application(s) and update the server.  You may want to add some kind of "locking" mechanism in to prevent new instances of the application from begin started until the update process has completed....

Answer (score 0):

Update the jar file and put it in a new location. Then change your classpath to pick up the updated jar from new location instead of old location. If a file is found at both the places then you can decide the preference based on your requirement. Another important point is if same jar is referenced multiple times then the one which comes first in the order in your classpath will be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Create two folders: old and new

Both of them will contain the same file. When there is no update, everybody will use the file from the new folder. When there is an update, copy the jar from the new folder into the old folder and every new connection will use the jar file in the old folder until every connection to the jar file in the new folder dies. Finally, when everybody uses the jar file in the old folder, copy your update into the new folder (of course, all of this should be automatical), finally, after the update is completed every new connection will use the jar file in the new folder. I hope this helps.